# Error reading 'manpage' of homebrew package manager

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, homebrew

I'am unable to execute the `man brew` command. Instead I get the following output:

> No such file or directory
>   Error reading man page /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
>
> No manual entry for brew

How can I relink or reinstall the manual to get the usage displayed correctly?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It looks like your manpages are missing for:

- brew
- brew-cask

I suggest you grab a copy of those two from [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tree/master/manpages) and store them in `/usr/local/Homebrew/manpages/`

**Original Answer**

Try to see if the page is actually installed:

```
find /usr -name brew.1 -ls
```

Try to see where `man` command is looking:

```
man -w
```

Comment: I executed the find command and got: `/usr/local/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1` and `/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1 -> ../../../Homebrew/manpages/brew.1`  for the pages. `man -w` is looking into `/usr/local/share/man/de:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/Library/TeX/texbin/man:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/share/man:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man` is there any path missing?

Comment: What do you get with `ls -l /usr/local/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1`

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 username admin  237  8 Nov 16:14 README.md`
`-rw-r--r--  1 username  admin    0 26 Jan 11:33 brew-cask.1`
`-rw-r--r--  1 username  admin    0 26 Jan 11:33 brew.1`